# how i use "for loop" in build custom keras.Layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I want build this **custom Layer** in keras to use it in sequential model. While running the code i am getting an error. my data looks like: X(200, 16, 3)) and y(200,).
can someone help me??
Below you can see the Code and the error.

my custom layar:

```
class WeightedLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, n_input, n_memb, **kwargs):
        super(WeightedLayer, self).__init__( **kwargs)
        self.n = n_input   # 16 features
        self.m = n_memb    # 3

    def build(self, batch_input_shape):
        super(WeightedLayer, self).build(batch_input_shape)

    def call(self, input_):
        CP = []
        self.batch_size = tf.shape(input_)[0]
        for batch in tf.range(self.batch_size):
            xd_shape = [self.m]
            c_shape = [1]
            cp = input_[batch,0,:]
            for d in range(1,self.n):
                c_shape.insert(0,self.m)
                xd_shape.insert(0,1)
                xd = tf.reshape(input_[batch,d,:], (xd_shape))
                c = tf.reshape(cp,(c_shape))
                cp = tf.matmul(c , xd)

            flat_cp = tf.reshape(cp,(1, self.m**self.n))
            CP.append(flat_cp)
        return tf.reshape(tf.stack(CP), (self.batch_size, self.m**self.n))

    def compute_output_shape(self, batch_input_shape):
        return tf.TensorShape([self.batch_size, self.m ** self.n])
```

when i use it in my model:

```
X_train = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (200, 16, 3))
X_test = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (200, 16, 3))
y_train = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (200,))
y_test = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (200,))

Model = keras.models.Sequential()
Model.add(Input(shape=(16, 3), name='inputLayer'))
Model.add(WeightedLayer(n_input=16, n_memb=3))
Model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
Model.fit(X_train, y_train,
         epochs=20,
         batch_size=10,
         validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

I am getting a following error:

```
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    693       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    694         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 695           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    696         else:
    697           raise

InaccessibleTensorError: in user code:

<ipython-input-66-5c6ffada5c7a>:29 call  *
    return tf.reshape(tf.stack(CP), (self.batch_size, self.m**self.n))
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper  **
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:1424 stack
    return gen_array_ops.pack(values, axis=axis, name=name)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py:6401 pack
    "Pack", values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:750 _apply_op_helper
    attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:597 _create_op_internal
    inp = self.capture(inp)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:647 capture
    % (tensor, tensor.graph, self))

InaccessibleTensorError: The tensor 'Tensor("weighted_layer_37/while/Reshape_30:0", shape=(1, 43046721), dtype=float32)' cannot be accessed here: it is defined in another function or code block. Use return values, explicit Python locals or TensorFlow collections to access it. Defined in: FuncGraph(name=weighted_layer_37_while_body_44082, id=139893449741456); accessed from: FuncGraph(name=weighted_layer_37_scratch_graph, id=139893452012688).
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have same issue.